# changing from GameScene to UIViewController after game ended

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4

After the game in the GameScene ended, the view should go back to my HomeViewController, but all it does is a SIGBRT - error

in the GameScene, I have the following code:

```
var gameEnded: (() -> Void)?
```

after the game finishes:

```
self.gameEnded?()
```

and in the GameViewController:

```
scene.gameEnded = {
    let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    self.present(homeViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try delegate:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import SpriteKit

protocol GameSceneDelegate: class {

    func gameSceneDidFinished(scene: GameScene)
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    weak var controllerDelegate: GameSceneDelegate?
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        guard let skView = self.view as? SKView else {
            return
        }

        let gameScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        gameScene.controllerDelegate = self
        skView.presentScene(gameScene)
    }
}

extension GameViewController: GameSceneDelegate {

    func gameSceneDidFinished(scene: GameScene) {

        let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        self.present(homeViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

}
```